# asp.net mvc binding selected dropdownlist value to model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm getting the following error when trying to bind the selected value from a dropdownlist to the model:

`An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional information: Value cannot be null.`

Here is my code:

**MODELS:**

```
public class Countries
{
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public List<Countries> CountryDDL { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public ActionResult Register()
{
    var model = new ViewModel();
    model.CountryDDL = new List<Countries>(_uiRepository.GetAllCountries());

    return View(model);
}
```

**VIEW**

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Country)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Country, new SelectList(Model.CountryDDL, "CountryCode", "Country"), "--Select a Country--", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Best guess is that this is occurring only when you post and return the view? (you need to repopulate `CountryDDL` before returning the view)

Comment: Thanks @Stephen Muecke! I'm not sure how you were able to determine that from what I posted, but that was exactly what was happening.

Comment: Because the only possible cause based on the code you have shown is that `Model.CountryDDL` is `null` (the `SelectList` constructor throws it) and its definitely not `null` in the GET method. You should edit your question to include the POST method and explain where/when it happens so this can be answered